# Can I change background in fullscreen mode "showAll" ?

Tags: livecode

When I set into "showAll" mode, the background appear in white screen. Can I change the background from white screen to image?

Comment: what platform are you targeting?  The showall mode shouldn't change the background, so if you have an image, etc.  it should still be there.

Comment: I set stack width and height is 1024*768. It's size for iPad. But my platform are iOS,Android,Windows. On windows platform I set fullscreen of stack is true and I set fullscreen mode to "showAll". The background is white screen.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug to me.  Confirm that you are running a stable version.  And please consider making a report if you do not find that it was your error.